# Access local website via router

Tags: xampp, wamp

a few months ago I've made it using Wamp Server
but now I'm trying to go inside of the local website via router to xampp and wamp server.

wamp ruinning on port 80
xampp on port 81
my local ip is `192.168.1.100`
so I've tried to go into 
`192.168.1.100` and `192.168.1.100:81`

From here it works, but from another computer (connected in the same network) cannot find it.

I've set wamp online and in both wamp and xampp set 'allow from all' so what it doens't work?

Also, I'm trying to do it because I want to test something on Node.js
(I know i can do t using 2 tabs or browsers)
When i start node.js server it may run at `127.0.0.1:8000` it would be acessible by `192.168.1.100:8000` ?

Thanks for reading and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using Windows 7? Do you have a firewall enabled? If so follow the steps in the link below to open ports 80 and 81 by setting custom inbound rules.

http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/

Comment: I'm using WindowsXP
How I've missed firewall, thanks for answer